# Go converting data to parquet

Tags: go, parquet

I am getting data from dynamodb and converting data to parquet files.

For the conversion to parquet files, I am using https://github.com/xitongsys/parquet-go library. But for some reason I am getting `runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference`

I know this error means that a pointer is nil and I am trying to use it or dereference it.

Not sure why pw.WriteStop() is giving memory invalid error

code:

```
fw, err := local.NewLocalFileWriter(parquetFile)
if err != nil {
    log.Errorf("local.NewLocalFileWriter() error - %s", err)
    return err
}

pw, err := writer.NewParquetWriter(fw, new(Struct), int64(len(tenantList)))
if err != nil {
    log.Errorf("writer.NewParquetWriter() error - %s", err)
    return err
}

pw.RowGroupSize = 128 * 1024 * 1024 //128M
pw.CompressionType = parquet.CompressionCodec_SNAPPY

for _, data := range tenantList {
    if err = pw.Write(data); err != nil {
        return err
    }
}

// this line gives memory invalid error
if err = pw.WriteStop(); err != nil {
    return err
}

fw.Close()
```

The only error that I am getting is "runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference". By printing statements in the "if" statements I found that invalid memory address is coming from "pw.WriteStop()"

Attaching a screenshot of the error; just to show that I am really getting only "runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference"

[image: runtime error]

Comment: The full error with the stack should show where the error happens. Add the stack to your post.

Comment: The runtime reports the line of code where the panic happened.  Edit the question to show that line of code.

Comment: The only error that I am getting is this "runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference" by printing statements in the "if" statements I found that invalid memory address is coming from "pw.WriteStop"

Comment: @jackysatpal runtime errors aka panics also print a stack trace, that's what the above comments are saying, that trace can be used to find the piece of code that causing the problem.

Comment: @jackysatpal see for example here: https://play.golang.com/p/oseauSuhEMV all the text after `panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference` is the stack trace, can you see how it mentions the file and line of the problem? i.e. `../prog.go:12`? Add the stack trace to the question or just use it yourself to track the problem.

Comment: yes, I do understand what people are saying about panic/runtime errors but the only thing I am getting is "invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference"

The website also shares the same error 
https://www.gitmemory.com/issue/xitongsys/parquet-go/134/496404784

Comment: @jackysatpal I see... so the problem would seem to be with the implementation of that package, it seems to be returning a plain error whose message is "runtime error....", you may have to open an issue on their github page.

Comment: I have attached a screenshot of the image just to show that I am really getting "run time error" and nothing else

Answer (score 0):

I faced this too. Figured out that it is because I haven't specified 'type=BOOLEAN' for bool fields in the struct tags, e.g. `parquet:"name=MyFieldName, type=BOOLEAN"`. For me, supplying BOOLEAN for bool, INT64 for int64 and UTF8 for string Go types worked.

Ideally the library should pick up data types automatically, but probably it's a feature not implemented, or it involves too much overhead and that's why intentionally not implemented.